# lambda@edge redirect to api gateway

Tags: aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront, aws-lambda-edge

I have a lambda@edge at viewer-request. I need this lambda@edge to redirect to an api gateway endpoint depending on the host value. Here is my code:

```
    const request = event.Records[0].cf.request;
    const domain = request.headers.host[0].value;
    const tenant = domain.split('.')[0];
    const uri = request.uri;

    var params = {
        TableName : 'table',
        Key: {
            "id": tenant,
            "disabled": 0
        }
    };
    dynamoDBClient.get(params, function(err, data) {
        let response = null;
        if (err) {
            response = {
                status: '400',
                body: "Error"
            };
        } else {
            if (data.Item) {
                response = {
                    status: '302',
                    headers: {
                        'location': [{ key: 'Location', value: data.Item.api + uri }]
                    }
                };
            } else {
                response = {
                    status: '400',
                    body: JSON.stringify(event)
                };
            }
        }
        callback(null, response);
    });
```

It looks like the problem is that I can not reach any api gateway endpoint. All endpoints return:

```
{
    "message": "Missing Authentication Token"
}
```

Is this the right way to redirect to api gateway endpoints? Or am I missing some configuration to reach the endpoint?